# child process kill itself after 3 seconds in fork

Tags: c++, fork

I have a fork function that creates a child process and a parent process

I would like  the child process to kill itself as soon as 3 seconds passes, using the **kill(child, SIGKILL)** function, that means withoutt using the **exit()** function. However I am not sure of the implementation. I tried using the kill function signal right after the while loop end, but it does not kill the child.

I tried to put it at the end of the main function, but it kills the child before 3 seconds passes

I tried to put it in a function that is called as soon as the while loop ends, but it did not kill the child

How can I do this with a better implementation that actually works ?

here is my code with comments available:

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int seconds = 3;
    int child;

    pid = fork();
    int i = 0;



    if(pid == 0)          //this is the child
    {
        child = getpid();

        while( i <= seconds)
        {
            cout << " second " << i << endl;
            sleep(1);
            i++;

        }
        killChild(child);     //function called after 3 seconds passes

    }

    else if(pid < 0)        //error statement
    {
        cout << " we have an error " << endl;
    }

    else                //parent if pid > 0
    {
        cout << " I am the parent " << endl;
        sleep(1);

    }

    //kill(child, SIGKILL)  placing it here will kill child before seconds passes

}


void killChild(int child)       //function to kill child (NOT KILLING IT)
{
    kill(child, SIGKILL);
}
```

Comment: Do you want the parent to kill the child or the child to kill itself?

Comment: because if you want the child to kill itself, there's no need for that - you could just `exit()` the child. you'd only need kill if you want the parent to kill the child.

Comment: Why not just put the 3sec-delay and child killing in the parent's code?

Comment: @e0k I will edit my question. I want it to kill itself

Comment: @MarcB I do not want to use exit. I will also edit my question that I want to use signal kill to do it

Comment: How do you know it's not working?  A process killing itself will look very similar to a process exiting.

Comment: @e0k  when I put it at the end of the main function I get the message ("Killed"), I do not get that when calling it after 3 seconds inside the child process if statement

Comment: "*I tried to put it in a function that is called as soon as the while loop ends, but it did not kill the child.*" How did you determine that? You ignore the return value of `kill`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I thought the function kill returns ("Killed") without printing it or using return syntax. That is what it returns when I put it at the end of main function, only problem is it does not wait for 3 seconds to pass

Comment: If you don't reap the child with `wait` then the child will remain a zombie even after it dies.

Comment: The parent does not have the child's PID in the variable `child`, only the child assigns it there.  Putting `kill(child, SIGKILL)` in at the end of `main()` (the commented line) will be executed by _both_ child and parent.  The parent does not wait 3 sec. and will send `SIGKILL` to a garbage value PID.

Comment: @MohamadZein That is incorrect. The `kill` function doesn't print anything.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it does print `Killed` when I place it at the end of the main function. but I just learned because it will be executed by both parent and child.

Comment: @e0k so placing it outside of the while loop the way I have it does kill the child ? and if so how can I output that, should I just put a `cout` after the kill function saying that child is killed ?

Comment: When you say "it does print `Killed`", what do you think the "it" is that you're referring to?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I would expect ... it is the signal kill function itself printing `Killed` ? is that correct ? I do not know what else would print this

Comment: My previous comment should have explained why the commented `kill(child, SIGKILL)` does **not** kill the child.

Comment: Nope. The `kill` function doesn't print anything. (Think about it. What could it print it to?) And the killed process doesn't print anything. How could it, it's dead. When you see the message "Killed", it's because something that was monitoring a process for you noticed that the process had been killed and is reporting that to you.

Comment: Please use waitpid() function after fork(). That may help.

Comment: so does the parent pid print it ? because the original process was killed ? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: No. How could the parent print it? There's no code in the parent to do that. All you did is call `kill`. You see the message "Killed" when, and only when, something monitoring a process for you notices that the process it was monitoring had been killed. That's a reliable indication that process was killed if, and only if, you know for a fact that you've directed something to monitor that process.

Comment: @e0k I meant the way I have if after the while loop directly and not at the end of the main function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and the process it was monitoring in this instance is the parent process ?

Comment: If you launched it form a shell that monitors processes it creates or inherits, then yes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I did launch it from a shell, that makes sense thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 void killChild(int sigNum)//Argument here is signal number
    {
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
    }  


  int main()
    {
        pid_t pid;
        int child;
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0)//this is the child
        {
            signal(SIGALRM,killchild)
            child = getpid();
            alarm(3); //set alarm for 3 seconds
            while(1); //continue to loop until 3 seconds passed
        }

        else if(pid < 0)//error statement
        {
            cout << " we have an error " << endl;
        }

        else//parent if pid > 0
        {
            cout << " I am the parent " << endl;
        }
    }

   After 3 seconds, alarm() function will generate SIGALRM and on this signal egneration, your killchild() function will be called and kill child.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this did not work. the while loop kept going and no alarm was generated

Comment: I think it does not matter what argument you are passing since you are calling the kill function on getpid()

Comment: Actually, signal handlers always take signal num argument to detect that for which signal generation, which signal handler needs to be executed.